# Doctrine getClassMetadata always returning class does not exist

Tags: php, events, doctrine

I want to get class metadata using getClassMetadata() from entity manager. But it always says 'class does not exist'. When I checked the class existence using class_exists(), it says true. Does anyone have the same problem?

Here is my sample code.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
....
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args){

    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $obj = $args->getEntity();
    $meta = $em->getClassMetadata((new \ReflectionClass($obj))->getName());

  }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just using `get_class`?

Comment: @iainn when I used get_class to get class name, it returns error "The class 'App\\EventSubscriber\\LivedEntitySubscriber' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\\Entity"